# Web App:Error page to be displayed to User After X unsuccessful authentication from a specific IP

Tags: security, servlets, web-applications, jsf-2

I have a web application running on JSF 2.0. Now the web application is exposed on Intranet.

We encountered a severe problem related to security.

- Some user have tried to access the application. Since we have enforced the maximum number of login attempts check at application, login was not successful.

But we encountered a security problem and is possibly seeking a solution.

I would like that a user trying to access an application for X number of times from a specific IP and failing to authenticate himself on application should not see the application webpage/instead an error page be shown indicating Security violation.

SO, a user from Ip 10.10.10.10:9000 trying to access application for 10 times and failing to authenticate himself on application should on 11th attempt be shown an error page indicating security violation.

Can someone suggest how can we approach this ?.

Answer (score 0):

In your login bean

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()); 

String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

You could the store this info and the count , in the cookie , or much safer in DB

Comment: Don't store this in a cookie as the user would just need to clear their cookies in order to reset the failed login count. Log each attempt in a database (date/time + IP), then you can analyse the data from the past 30 minutes or so to work out if the number of attempts is above a threshold. You're better off throttling responses rather than total lock out, as then you do not deny legitimate users access to their accounts (in case of shared IP).

Comment: Now having done this, as I have asked in the question, I would like the user not to even show the authentication page if the request comes from that IP.. Showing him not authorized after doing an authentication is relatively simple. I guess the concept of servlet filter will come into picture. Can someone provide any guidance ..??